# Trouble with placing marker on the board in naughts and crosses game in python

Tags: python

I am creating a naughts and crosses game for an n x n game (the user will input what size the board will be).

So far, I have been able to create the board that has underscores in each element of the list after the user inputs what size they want the board to be.

However, my problem is that when the player puts down a marker, which they do by entering the row number, and then the column number, **it enters the marker for the entire column.**

For example, the line where the marker is put on the board is this one:         `board[int(row)-1][int(column)-1] = symbol`. If the user enters 1, 1, then it should put a marker in the very top left of the board, in row 1 and column 1. But it enters the marker for the entire column. I am very confused as to why it is doing this. Help appreciated!

(The lines under `#Checking if someone won` are irrelevant for this question. The main lines to look at are under `#Putting the marker on the board` and `#Creating the board`.)

```
#todo:
#check if marker already is there

board = []
empty_list = []

board_length = input("How many rows would you like for the board? ")
while board_length.isdigit() == False:
    board_length = input("That is not a number. How many rows would you like for the board? ")

#Creating the Board
for x in range(int(board_length)):
    board.append(empty_list)
    board[x].append('_')

#Printing the board
for i in range(len(board)):
    print(board[i])

print(board)
print ("Player 1 is X (Crosses), Player 2 is O (Naughts). Let's begin!")

player_turn = True
symbol = "X"
symbols = ["X","O"]
player_name = "1"

#Setting correct answers for coordinates
correct_answers = []
for i in range(len(board)):
    correct_answers.append(str(i+1))

#Game
for i in range(len(board)**2):
    global player_turn
    if player_turn == True:
        symbol = "X"
        player_name = "1"
    else:
        symbol = "O"
        player_name = "2"

    #Making sure the coordinates entered are correct
    row = input("Player " + player_name + ": Please enter the row for your marker: ")
    while row not in correct_answers:
        row = input("Invalid answer. Please enter the row for your marker: ")

    column = input("Player " + player_name + ": Please enter the column for your marker: ")
    while column not in correct_answers:
        column = input("Invalid answer. Please enter the column for your marker: ")

    #Putting the marker on the board
    board[int(row)-1][int(column)-1] = symbol

    #find and remove symbol from where it isn't supposed to be?

    for n in range(len(board)):
        print(n)
        print(board[n])

    player_turn = not player_turn

    #Checking if someone won
    game_over = False
    for i in range(len(board)):
        the_set = set(board[i])

        if len(the_set) == 1 and '_' not in the_set:
            print(str(symbols.index(board[i][0])) + " wins by row " + str(i+1) + "!")
            break

        board_list = []
        for x in range(len(board)):
            board_list.append(board[x][x])
            if x == len(board) - 1 and len(set(board_list)) == 1 and '_' not in board_list:
                print(str(symbols.index(board_list[0])) + " wins by diagonal (top left to right)!")
                game_over = True
                break
            if game_over == True:
                break

        board_list = []
        for x in range(len(board)):
            board_list.append(board[x][len(board)-1-x])

            if x == len(board) - 1 and len(set(board_list)) == 1 and '_' not in board_list:
                print(str(symbols.index(board_list[0])) + " wins by diagonal (top right to left)!")
                game_over = True
                break
            if game_over == True:
                break

        board_list = []
        for x in range(len(board)):
            board_list.append(board[x][i])

            if x == len(board) - 1 and len(set(board_list)) == 1 and '_' not in board_list:
                print(str(symbols[symbols.index(board_list[0])]) + " wins by column " + str(i+1) + "!")
                game_over = True
                break
            if game_over == True:
                break
        if game_over == True:
            break

    if game_over == True:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
board.append(empty_list)
```

to:

```
board.append([])
```

By using the same empty_list over and over, you are creating many references to the same list.  When you change the list later, it is visible through all of the references.

This is explained more in depth here: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201308/names_and_values_making_a_game_board.html